# Is it acceptable to add the dedication of a chapter in an academic scientific book?

Tags: journals, books, publishers

Is it acceptable to add the dedication of a chapter in an academic scientific book? Is there a way to thank the ones who supported me though writing the chapters?

Answer (score 5):

In general, yes, you can do that, but the editor that handles the book might advise otherwise if they have a preferred/required style. But a book's contents are up to the authors.

Unless you are told otherwise, write the first draft for submission as you like. There will be edits required in nearly every case.

And, if you self publish then the decisions are yours to make.

Note that the dedication might go in the front-matter rather than with the specific chapter: "Chapter 6 is dedicated to...".